# lesscss : string interpolation, mixin and condition

Tags: css, less

How can i use string interpolation in a mixin with condition ?

my less file :

```
@line-height-topbar : 1.43;
@line-height-base : 1.43;

.topbar {
color : #000;
.lineHeight(topbar);
}
```

my mixin :

```
.lineHeight(@prefix,@line-height-base) when not (~"@{line-height-@{prefix}}" = @line-height-base) {
    line-height: ~"@{line-height-@{prefix}}";
}
```

the css output :

```
.topbar {
color : #000;
line-height : 1.43;
}
```

Normally, i expected this css (because @line-height-topbar = @line-height-base) :

```
.topbar {
color : #000;
}
```

Comment: for me your LESS code doesn't compile (using version 1.5.1). Are you sure you've pasted all the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassigning to another local variable seemed to work, like so:

```
.lineHeight(@prefix; @check: ~"@{line-height-@{prefix}}") when not (@check = @line-height-base) {
    line-height: ~"@{line-height-@{prefix}}";
}
```

It may have something to do with the processing order of how/when the `~"@{line-height-@{prefix}}"` is resolved.